# Does installing the proprietary Nvidia driver fix the frequent system hang/crash problem with the nouveau driver on Fedora 27?

Tags: fedora, drivers, nvidia, video, nouveau

There are several blog posts describing how to install the proprietary Nvidia gpu/graphics card driver on older versions of F27 running wayland. Some suggest that others approaches may cause compatibility problems with other software libraries and repositories/repos.

When using the default supplied nouveau driver on Fedora 27 f27 with 4 monitors and a GTX 750Ti card my system hangs with every few hours of use. This may also have been the case in prior versions also.

Does installing the proprietary Nvidia driver fix the frequent system hang/crash problem? What is the safest way to install it, especially if one wants to use the GPU for computation, such as AI/ML?

Comment: negativo17 is the only way to fly.